# How to customize advanced key bindings in Visual Studio (Emacs style)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using this extension: [Emacs emulation for Visual Studio](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/09dc58c4-6f47-413a-9176-742be7463f92). But `Meta-N -> 5 Lines down` `Meta-P 5 lines up` doesn't work.

How can I customize and add these bindings to Visual Studio?

Comment: This isn't really an Emacs question since it concerns a plugin for VS that *emulates* Emacs keybindings.